# Oracle Spool adds extra LF

Tags: oracle, spool

I have a Spool of a Select as :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1

set heading off
set feedback off
set termout off
set echo off
set verify off
set pagesize 0
set line 1000
set trimspool on
spool &1
SELECT '9' || 'c' || chr(10) || myColumn
  FROM myTable;
spool off
set feedback on;
set term on;


exit;
```

The problem is that my output file is as folows:

```
9c
17

9c
17

9c
17

9c
17

9c
17
```

So As you see I have my Line Feed after 'c' but it adds a new line feed after myColumn also.
Any ideas how to solv it ?
My file will be loaded in Unix.
I've tryied with a CR instead but then I'll have lines with CR and others with LF. 
I think it will fail between Unix and Windows.

Comment: It's Ok, I got it. Using a SET RECSEP OFF worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET RECSEP OFF
SET RECSEP WRAPPED
```

http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html